# Generating a random number in the inner click event of nested click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate a random number in the innest event click of a nested events clicks; but instead of a single number I get lot of them.

The code is as follows:

```
$("#onePl").click(function(){
   $("#firstP").fadeOut("slow",function(){
      $("#secondP").fadeIn("slow",function(){
          $("#theX").click(function(){
             $("#secondP").fadeOut("slow",function(){
               $("table").fadeIn("slow");
                **var ran=Math.random();// *I want a single random number***
                **console.log(ran);// I get lot of random numbers**
                           })

                      })
                 })
            })
      })
```

Comment: can you post fiddle for this?

Comment: Yes , the fiddle is: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cortazar11/16mxsu8r/)

Answer (score 0):

Nesting the binding of clicking events will have undesired effects, because everytime the outer click event gets fired, a new binding of the inner event is added.

Your code should look like this

```
$("#onePl").click(function(){
    $("#firstP").fadeOut("slow",function(){
        $("#secondP").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});

$("#theX").click(function(){
    $("#secondP").fadeOut("slow",function(){
        $("table").fadeIn("slow");
        **var ran=Math.random();// *I want a single random number***
        **console.log(ran);// I get lot of random numbers**
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was the point. The second click out of the first one do the same and it generates only one random number.

Comment: Glad it helped! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.